Sorting ID in QtableView module
I'm using pyside6. I have a QtableView module which displays data inputed by 'customer'. If customer delete transaction and creates new the ID it receives is considered the next number from the maximum ID in the list. Example i have list of 5 ID I delete id number 3 and create new it gets id 6, but now my list looks like 1, 2, 4, 5, 6.
How i can sort ID in list that way, if i delete id number 3, ID number 4 would become id 3, and others gone become lover
Code which create database
    def create_connection(self):
        db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        db.setDatabaseName('Money_db.db')

        if not db.open():
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, "Cannot open database",
                                           "Click Cancel to exit.", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
            return False

        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expenses (ID integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, Date VARCHAR(20), "
                   "Category VARCHAR(20), Description VARCHAR(20), Balance REAL, Status VARCHAR(20))")
        return True

Code which making new transaction
    def add_new_transaction_query(self, date, category, description, balance, status):
        sql_query = "INSERT INTO expenses (Date, Category, Description, Balance, Status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        self.execute_query_with_params(sql_query, [date, category, description, balance, status])

Code which execute QtableView
class MoneyManager(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MoneyManager, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUI(self)
        self.conn = Data()
        self.view_data()

    def view_data(self):  
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model.setTable('expenses')
        self.model.select()
        self.ui.tableView.setModel(self.model)

I want to create a function that take data from db and update it, but was stuck because of skill issues in python and sqlite. If the only way is to create a function can you give a hint or some code examples for me to understand with what i can start writing a function.

Deleting a record doesn't change (nor should) the rowid of the others, as values are not dynamic. Also, the sqlite docs explain that the AUTOINCREMENT keyword prevents to reuse IDs of deleted rows, so you shouldn't use it anyway. If you only need this for display purposes, then subclass QSqlTableModel and override data() so that it always returns the row number. If, otherwise, you really need the sql ID to always be consecutive and consistent with the row number, then you need to manually update each following row whenever any row is deleted.
